# Javascript tag is not apprearing in html on rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I am a beginner in Javascript and html. I have created a javascript tag that adds rows to a html table on rails. It seems to me that the script tag is not getting executed. I am not getting any error as well.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  //Make a javascript array from a Ruby array 
  //Use the array to create tables in html with proper value
  var myArray = new Array();
  <%@array.each_with_index do |name, index|%>
  myArray[index] = <%= name[:employee]%>
  <%end%>

  var arraylen = myArray.length;

  //Javascript function to add table 

  $(function() {
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    for (var i = 0; i<arraylen; i++){

      var row = table.insertRow(index);
      var name = myArray[i]
      row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = name.value;
    }
  })();

</script>
```

Comment: I am not sure if this will make any change or not but please try putting `<%= name[:employee]%>` in double quotes like this: `"<%= name[:employee]%>"` when being assigned to the array index.

Comment: I tried. But no change. I also added alert(); and console.log(); inside the script tag but even I am not able to see their outputs.

Comment: Okay one thing what you can do to test is just create a dummy array and run the code which is inside `$(function()){}` from browser console and see if it adds anything or not. If you succeed then your code is correct and there is some other problem.

Comment: @Deep I checked and learned that "index" variable was not set. After that it works. even "<%= name[:employee]%>" helped me in getting the value from rails array and include it as string value in javascript array variable. Thanks!

Comment: Oh that's great so without the double quotes the value was not being inserted right?

Comment: Yes. It was showing some error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you found out in your `script` the `index` variable you have used is not set to any value. Instead it is intended to use `i` or you can set any value required.

Also you are assigning a value to javascript array using the `erb` syntax to so whenever assigning the value to javascript as a `String` you should put it inside string quotes. Like this:

```
myArray[index] = "<%= name[:employee]%>"
```

So the value will be assigned as `String` in your javascript array.